# Sending images with iOS 8 custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, swift, ios8

I've been developing a custom keyboard for iOS 8, but stumbled upon a problem trying to send images using the keyboard. I did some research and it seems like there isn't a simple way to do this with `UITextDocumentProxy` because only `NSStrings` are allowed.

Am I either overlooking any simple ways to use a custom keyboard to send images and/or is there any way to work around this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, [you are not the only person to try a keyboard like this](http://www.engadget.com/2014/09/12/popkey-animated-gif-keyboard/). If you look at the animated GIF on the site, the keyboard uses copy/paste to add the image to the messages.

The [UIKeyInput Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIKeyInput/insertText:), which is inherited by [UITextDocumentProxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextDocumentProxy_Protocol/index.html), has the following function:

```
func insertText(_ text: String)     //Swift
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text //ObjC
```

These only take a String or an NSString, as you already know. Because there are no other methods to insert content, it can be assumed that, currently, there is no other way.

Right now, I would suggest that you adopt a similar usage. When the user taps on the image, add it to the UIPasteboard. Maybe present a little banner on top of the keyboard saying, "You can now paste" or something, but that would be up to you to decide.

Comment: How does the Emoji app that is fairly commonly used insert images? Isn't that a 3rd party app also? Though I know that one has been around long before iOS8 came out with 3rd party keyboard support.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 emoji are Unicode characters. They do not count as images.

Comment: I'm using this block. on my custom keyboard view but doesn't work. 
@erdekhayser


var pasteboard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteboard.persistent = true
pasteboard.image = image

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work for me either, when I paste the image into the UITextView or UITextField, I get something like: 8C:2D:AA:7C:85:A6

Comment: Here Same Problem I have copied image to Pasteboard but cant paste dont show paste.

Comment: allow full access to your keyboard by going in to the setting > general> keyboard> your-keyboard> allow full access