# How to send an image with custom keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, emoji, custom-keyboard

I am building my first custom keyboard. I am using Swift 2 and Xcode 7. I have this as my keyboard

[image: Keyboard]

(I am running it on my iPhone) When I tap the little alien face, I would like to have either

1. a little emoji with that image or
2. insert the image (if possible) to where the user is typing. I have tried this code

   ```
   let pasteboard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
   let image: UIImage = currentImage!
   let newImage = scaleImage(image, toSize: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
   let imgData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)!
   pasteboard.setData(imgData, forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardTypeListImage[0] as! String)

   let proxy = UITextDocumentProxy.self as! UITextDocumentProxy
   let data = pasteboard.string!
   print(data)
   proxy.insertText(data)
   ```

but I have been unsuccessful. When I `print(data)`, I receive `nil`, followed by an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the next line. How can I achieve either of the 2 goals I had? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No. Somebody posted an answer earlier, and we were discussing it in the comments. I asked him a question and he never replied. I guess he deleted his post. Do you have a solution?

Comment: After some additional research I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25827906/3489599. It's a little old, so this might have changed since then, but as of right now that is the only thing I have found to answer the question. Unfortunately, that answer is No.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem did u find any solution for this?

Comment: No :( However, I have found that most iOS keyboards with images tend to copy the image to the clipboard then tell the user to paste it. I believe this is the only workaround to this as of now

Comment: Do you have any solution for this, @PranavWadhwa ? Please help me with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 5:

```swift
import MobileCoreServices

guard
    let newImage = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"),
    let imgData = newImage.pngData()
else { return }

UIPasteboard.general.setData(imgData, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePNG as String)
```

Also set your keyboard extension info.plist to:

```
<dict>
    <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
    <string>en-US</string>
    <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Ketan, your comment was life saver. Thanks

Comment: This just copy image to pasteboard. How can you paste image from pasteboard to chat section on iMessage?. Thanks.